# file upload mime type issue with Multer Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, multer

in my project, I got to upload a Photoshop file with Multer but when I put the mime type of photoshop, wave, and mp3 files I got this error:

```
Error: Mime type invalide
at DiskStorage.destination [as getDestination] (C:\Users\21653\Desktop\vagaBeats\back\src\midlleware\artworkImageUploader.js:14:21)
at DiskStorage._handleFile (C:\Users\21653\Desktop\vagaBeats\back\node_modules\multer\storage\disk.js:31:8)
at C:\Users\21653\Desktop\vagaBeats\back\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:144:17
at allowAll (C:\Users\21653\Desktop\vagaBeats\back\node_modules\multer\index.js:8:3)
at wrappedFileFilter (C:\Users\21653\Desktop\vagaBeats\back\node_modules\multer\index.js:44:7)
at Busboy.<anonymous> (C:\Users\21653\Desktop\vagaBeats\back\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:114:7)
at Busboy.emit (events.js:315:20)
at Busboy.emit (C:\Users\21653\Desktop\vagaBeats\back\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:38:33)
at PartStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\21653\Desktop\vagaBeats\back\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:213:13)
at PartStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

this is my code:

```js
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require('path');

const MIME_TYPE_MAP = {
    "image/png": "png",
    "image/jpeg": "jpg",
    "image/jpg": "jpg",
    "file/psd": "psd" // i got a problem with this MIME TYPE
};

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        const isValid = MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
        let error = new Error("Mime type invalide");
        if (isValid) {
            error = null;
        }
        cb(error, path.join(__dirname, '../../', 'images/artworkImages'));
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const name = file.originalname
            .toLowerCase()
            .split(" ")
            .join("-");
        console.log(file)
        const ext = MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
        cb(null, name + "-" + Date.now() + "." + ext);
    }
});

module.exports = multer({ storage: storage }).fields([
{ name: "Image"},
{name:"untagedartwork"},
{name:"psd_file"} //this is the file that i want to upload it to the server
]);
```

can you please help me to resolve this problem

Comment: You can put a console.log(file.mimetype) above this line `const isValid = MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];` to see the value.

Answer (score 1):

Try to chage `file/psd` to some of this (the first one should work):

```
image/vnd.adobe.photoshop

application/x-photoshop

application/photoshop

application/psd

image/psd
```

Comment: thanks for your help the first one work without any problems

Comment: I am glad to hear that. Consider to vote and approve my answer if it helped you.